# cannot convert 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int printf(const char*, ...)'

Tags: c, char, wchar

I never try coding in C for the last four or five years so I don't know how to solve this problem.

My code is like this:

```c
char szExePath[MAX_PATH]; //
//"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Application Verifier\\vrfauto.dll"
printf("Please input the execution file path:\n");
scanf("%s", szExePath);
//char LPCWSTR
WCHAR wsz[64];
swprintf(wsz, L"%S", szExePath);
LPCWSTR m_szFilename = wsz;

setlocale(LC_ALL, "chs");
_tprintf(m_szFilename);
```

Comment: this is C, not C++

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ As suggested by @CinCout, you should tag your past properly with 'C'. Also, I just Googled the title of your question and found 4-5 SO answers that already exist... You should do the same, in case one of them helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your project configuration, `_tprintf()` maps to either `printf()` when `TCHAR` maps to `char`, or maps to `wprintf()` for `wchar_t`. Clearly your project is set to map `TCHAR` to `char`, which is why you are getting an error about passing a `wchar_t*` to `printf()`.

But, the code you showed is not using `TCHAR`, so you should not be using  `_tprintf()` at all. `m_szFilename` is explicitly a `wchar_t[]`, so just use `wprintf()` directly instead:

```c
wprintf(m_szFilename);
```

Also, consider using `wscanf()` to read the input as a `wchar_t[]` to begin with and not use an intermediate `char[]`:

```c
WCHAR szExePath[MAX_PATH]; //
//L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Application Verifier\\vrfauto.dll"
printf("Please input the execution file path:\n");
wscanf(L"%259s", szExePath);

setlocale(LC_ALL, "chs");
wprintf(szExePath);
```

Note, however, that whether you use `scanf()` or `wscanf()`, reading stops on whitespace, so if the user enters a path like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Application Verifier\vrfauto.dll"`, your buffer will receive only `"C:\Program`. To account for that, you would need to use `gets()`/`_getws()` (or the safer `gets_s()`/`_getws_s()`) or `fgets()`/`fgetws()` instead.

Comment: `gets` and `gets_s` are both discouraged, use `fgets`/`fgetws`.